# How to change nwidart Module Folder

Tags: laravel, modular

i use nwidart/laravel-modules in my laravel project.

By default Modules directory is in Module, and i will change the modules directory to app/Modules. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

we need to run `composer dump-autoload`